# Trying to open an image from a URL without the extention - VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I am currently trying to work on a database that stores a collection of cards, and I'm trying to fetch Images from Magic's Gatherer service in order to help identify the card.

This is the code I am currently Using:

```
Private Sub ID_Change()
    cardImage.Picture = "http://gatherer.wizards.com/Handlers/Image.ashx?multiverseid=" & ID.Column(0) & "&type=card"
End Sub
```

**cardImage** is a picture object

**ID** is a combo box, with the first column as a Long Integer.

Now then, my issue is that access isn't liking the URL that I'm providing it, and is throwing a Run-Time error 2220. Is there any way to get access to accept the URL as a JPEG, and load it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using an `Image` object, try using a `Web Browser Control` object and set its `.ControlSource` property, something like

```
Me.WebBrowser2.ControlSource = "=""http://gatherer.wizards.com/Handlers/Image.ashx?multiverseid=" & ID.Column(0) & "&type=card"""
```